# How to compute coefficients in Trinomial triangle at specific position?

Tags: polynomials, power-series, exponentiation

I need to compute coefficients of $i$-th power of $x$ from simplifying of $$(x^2 + x + 1)^n$$ 
From [that site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialTriangle.html) i know about trinomial triangle.

But how can compute coeficients of $i$-th element at $n$-th row without computing all upper elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote by
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m(s-1)}{\binom{m}{k}}_{s}x^{k}=(1 + x + ... + x^{s-1})^{m}\,$$ 
the expansion of multinomial of degree $s-1$

From that relation follow that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{m(s-1)}{\binom{m}{k}}_{s}x^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\binom{m}{k}}_{s}x^{k}=\left(\frac{1-x^{s}}{1-x}\right)^{m}=(1-x^{s})^{m}(1-x)^{-m}\,$$

from binomial formula we have

$$(1-x^{s})^{m}=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}x^{si}$$

and from Taylor formula

$$(1-x)^{-m}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+j-1}{j}x^{j}$$

after substitutions we get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\binom{m}{k}}_{s}x^{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}x^{si}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+j-1}{j}x^{j}=$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{m+j-1}{j}x^{si+j}=$$

$$ =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{m+k-si-1}{k-si}x^{k}\,$$

for $si+j=k$ follow that $j=k-si$ then equate the coefficients next to x follow formula

$${\binom{m}{k}}_{s}=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\binom{m}{i}\binom{m+k-si-1}{m-1}\,$$

put $s=3$ you get what you ask

Answer (score 2):

These are known as Gegenbauer polynomials. Specifically

$$
   (x^2+x+1)^n = \sum_{m=0}^\infty C_m^{(-n)}(-\frac{1}{2}) x^m
$$

This follows directly from generating function for these [polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials). There is also an explicit sum representation on that wikipedia page.

Also this sequence is known as trinomial coefficient, and typically denoted $T(n,m)$. See [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html) for example.

Comment: For computational purposes, it's better to use the three-term recurrence than to use the explicit sum representation, which is rather cancellation-prone.